# How to show element on click (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, html

In the below code I have 3 buttons with content under each one. When I click a button it shows the content of all the buttons. I want to only show the content of the clicked button.

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(".d-text").show();
});
```

```css
.d-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="item item1">button</button>
<p class="d-text">Dummy text</p>

<button class="item item2">button</button>
<p class="d-text">Dummy text</p>

<button class="item item3">button</button>
<p class="d-text">Dummy text</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `.next()`

```
$(this).next(".d-text").show();
```

This will only show the next `p` after the button your clicked.

**Demo**

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".d-text").show();
});
```

```css
.d-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="item item1">button</button>
<p class="d-text">Dummy text</p>

<button class="item item2">button</button>
<p class="d-text">Dummy text</p>

<button class="item item3">button</button>
<p class="d-text">Dummy text</p>
```

Comment: Just a *caveat* using `.next(selector)` - it doesn't do what it intuitively looks like it should.  In most cases you just want `.next()` (no selector).  `.next(selector)` is the same as `.next().filter(selector)` rather than `.nextAll().filter(select).first()`

Comment: Could be a matter of preference, however I would try to minimize the coupling between HTML structure and program logics.

Comment: @EriksKlotins True, you can always optimize something, but in this case, I believe that keeping it very simple so the OP can understand and learn from it since I don't think (apologize if I'm wrong) the OP has much experience jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a specific class/id to each p item so you can link together a specific button with the right text

https://jsfiddle.net/zdyw8ra4/

HTML:

```
<button class="item item1"data-target="#item1">button</button>
<p class="d-text"id="item1">Dummy text1</p>

<button class="item item2"data-target="#item2">button</button>
<p class="d-text" id="item2">Dummy text2</p>

<button class="item item3" data-target="#item3">button</button>
<p class="d-text"id="item3">Dummy text3</p>
```

JS:

```
$(".item").click(function() {
  $($(this).data('target')).toggle();
});
```